# How do I get a Vuetify component's SASS variables?

Tags: sass, vuetify.js

I'm trying to fit an image into Vuetify's `VBtn` component, like this-

```html
<template>
  <v-btn>
    <img class="img-in-btn" src="@/assets/my-image.png">
  </v-btn>
</template>
```

If I use the `v-img` and do it like-

```
<v-img :src="my-img" height="100%" width="100%" />
```

It still results in a very wide button and a huge image.

My current attempt is to grab `VBtn`'s dimensions directly from Vuetify's stylesheet, and apply it directly to image class selector like this-

```scss
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  @import '~vuetify/src/components/VBtn/_variables.scss';
  
  .img-in-btn {
    height: $btn-sizes;
    object-fit: contain;
  }
</style>
```

But this throws an error-

> `SassError: ("x-small": 20, "small": 28, "default": 36, "large": 44, "x-large": 52) isn't a valid CSS value.`

What's the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-btn/#sass), **$btn-sizes** is configured using the [map-deep-merge](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/map#deep-merge), like this-

```
map-deep-merge(
  (
    'x-small': 20,
    'small': 28,
    'default': 36,
    'large': 44,
    'x-large': 52
  ),
  $btn-sizes
);
```

**It means `$btn-sizes` has multiple mapped values that can not be assigned directly to any CSS property and this is why you are getting the error.**

Now, to get the **default key's value** use, [map-get function](https://www.w3schools.com/sass/sass_functions_map.php) like this-

```
map-get($btn-sizes, "default")
```

Here is the complete example-

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import "~vuetify/src/components/VBtn/_variables.scss";

.img-in-btn {
  height: map-get($btn-sizes, "default") + px !important;
}
</style>
```